# Very simple shopping cart lis / procurement form

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, related-list

So i've been searching all day for a way to do this, but as unbelievable it is, nobody seems to be looking for the same as i want. By the way I'm using Sharepoint 2013 foundation.

So I would like to create a procurement form fpr IT HW/SW requests. I thought I could solve this with 3 lists.

1. Procurement: Information abot User, Head of Department, Price limit etc.
2. Items: Type of Product, Name, Price, In Stock Quantity, etc.
3. Connection list of List 1 & 2: Quantity of Item, ID of Item, ID of Procurement.

So when creating a new procurement, there should be a list with all the items so far created. In this new form, the user should be able to select the items and add a certain quantity of those items (stored in list 3)

Hopefully someone can help with this.